# Separate subhash from hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash_of_student_and_grades.

```
{132=>{"Design"=>6, "English"=>5, "Humanities"=>5, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>6, "Music"=>7,
 "PE"=>6, "Science"=>6, "Theatre"=>6}, 
134=>{"Design"=>7, "English"=>6, "Humanities"=>6, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>5, "Music"=>6,
"PE"=>6, "Science"=>7, "Art"=>6}, 
136=>{"Design"=>5, "English"=>4, "Humanities"=>5, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>6, "Music"=>6,
"PE"=>7, "Science"=>5, "Theatre"=>6},...}
```

Now I want to make hash with key like this.

```
id132={"Design"=>6, "English"=>5, "Humanities"=>5, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>6, "Music"=>7,
 "PE"=>6, "Science"=>6, "Theatre"=>6}
id134={"Design"=>7, "English"=>6, "Humanities"=>6, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>5, "Music"=>6,
"PE"=>6, "Science"=>7, "Art"=>6}
...
...
```

UPDATE:

I have done this so far. But it does not assign each hash to key.

```
resulthash.each {|key, value| puts key=value} 

# outputs
{"Design"=>6, "English"=>5, "Humanities"=>5, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>6, "Music"=>7, "PE"=>6, "Science"=>6, "Theatre"=>6}
{"Design"=>7, "English"=>6, "Humanities"=>6, "Languages"=>6, "Math"=>5, "Music"=>6, "PE"=>6, "Science"=>7, "Theatre"=>6}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you should show us some code that you have tried, right? you are an old member!

Comment: also, I do not see any difference in the two hashes above?

Comment: Updated. It can be id132, id134 etc. FYI I'm new to Ruby.

Comment: You still need to clarify the question. The key is where you say, "Now I want to make hash with key like this." and then give an example that begins with `id132={...}`. In view of the answer you have checkmarked, you may wish to give the initial hash a name (e.g., `my_hash =`), and change the above-mentioned sentence to something like: "For each key `k` of `my_hash`, I wish to create an instance variable with a similar name and set it equal to `my_hash[k]`, like this:".  In addition change `id132=` to `@id132=`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use digits as variable names, but if it would be id132, id133 etc you can accomplish this using metaprogramming and instance variables:

```ruby
hash = {"i1"=>{"a"=>"b"}, "i2"=>{"c"=>"d"}}
hash.each { |key, value| instance_variable_set("@#{ key }", value) }
puts @i1 # => {"a"=>"b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Because you can(ruby gives you ability to shoot your foot),here is answer:

In ruby `id32` is the name of variable.
Hash's key can be any type: number, string... object.
Basic types(number, string, `nil`, `false`, `true`) are evaluated like this:

```
n1 = 2
n2 = 2
h = {2 => 42}
h[n1] # 42
h[n2] # 42
```

In other words you get/set hash's key `2` not `n1` or `n2`. It would be hard to change *basic types*.

Objects, on other hands, you can modify:

```
class N
  def initialize name
    @name=name #contains name, like `id32`, `id34`
  end

  def to_s #this method let you show any text, here name(for example `id32`)
    "#{@name}" 
  end
end

id32 = N.new 'id32'

h={id32 => 42}
#{id32=>42}

#adding more keys/values

id34 = N.new 'id34'
h[id34] = 'some value'
```

and... that's just basics.

### what lots of rubist do:

#### They use symbols.

#### What are symbols?

It's type like string but there can be only one symbol!

```
puts :a.object_id
puts :a.object_id
puts :a.object_id
```

Code above prints 3 the same numbers because `:a` is only 1.

```
puts 'a'.object_id
puts 'a'.object_id
```

Strings are *not the same*.

#### Construction:

You prepend characters with `:`:

```
`:a`
```

or if it has weird character, prepend with `:` and surround with `'` or `"`:

`:'a'`

### To sum up:

Your code will look exactly the same, will be faster(no need for objects like above):

```
h ={:a => :b}
```

or from 1.9.x(i don't remember correct number) you can use this syntax too:

```
h = {a: :b}
```

Comment: You might want to learn more about formatting on Stack Overflow. SO formatting is supposed to be similar to an encyclopedia, or Wikipedia. Don't make up your own method of formatting an answer, instead, mimic the look and feel of the other documents on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @theTinMan Well, aside some minor "not SO/Wikipedia style" I think it looks like one, check this section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Examples

Comment: You missed the point. Take the time to look around Stack Overflow; Mimic its look and feel, and write in the style of an encyclopedia. "ruby" should be consistently spelled "Ruby" unless it's part of a command-line example because it's a proper-name. "rubist" should be "Rubyist", "i" should be "I". Punctuation: A space always precedes "(" and follows "," in sentences. Sentences start with a capital letter "what lots of..." is "What...". Articles of speech are important, so use "a" and "the". Remember, potential employers and co-workers are reading.

Comment: @theTinMan Ah, you mean my English. Yes, I should improve myself. As for "ruby" vs "Ruby", thank you for pointing this out. I haven't known that but I remember discussion about "Perl" vs "perl".